# Compute the number of distinct actions of cyclic group $C_n$ on a set $X,$ s.t $|X|= n+1.$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, cyclic-groups, permutation-cycles

There are $n+1C_n = n+1$ combinations possible, with $n!/n= (n-1)! $ orderings possible in each; leading to a total of $(n+1).(n-1)!$.

Let $n= 6.$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138292/discussion-on-question-by-jiten-compute-the-number-of-distinct-actions-of-c-6).

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: first take the nine inequivalent actions . Sum up the cases.

Second, take the complement and subtract from 7!.
The complementary technique has cases:

a. $1\rightarrow(1234), $
b  $1\rightarrow(1234)(56), $
c. $1\rightarrow(1234)(567), $
d. $1\rightarrow(12345)(67), $
e. $1\rightarrow(12345). $
f. $1\rightarrow (1234567).$
Can subtract the sum of above six cases, from $7!$ to get actual value.

---

There are two techniques used:
First, is to sum up cases, as shown in comment by @StinkingBishop, let us call it : first way.
Second, is the usual approach - called : direct approach.

The complementary technique is easy as the computation is easier, using the first way.
The unwanted set of inequivalent actions is impossible to arrive in result.

---

The sum of complementary actions is:
a+b+c. $7C4.(4!/4).3!= 35.36= 1260.$
d+e. $7C5.(5!/5).2!=21.24.2=1008.$
f. $7C7.(7!/7)= 6!= 720.$
The sum is: $2268+720= 2988.$

This leaves after subtraction from $7!= 5040$ a value of $2052$.

While the direct approach consists of taking the sum of the below cases:

1.$1\rightarrow e, $
2. $1\rightarrow(123456), $
3. $1\rightarrow(12), $
4. $1\rightarrow(12)(34), $
5. $1\rightarrow(12)(34)(56),$
6. $1\rightarrow(123),$
7. $1\rightarrow(123)(456),$
8. $1\rightarrow(12)(345), $
9. $1\rightarrow(12)(345)(67).$

But, the number of cases here are more, else unwanted actions would be counted; as well as double-counting can arise.

By the direct approach, need find the different cases:

1. $1,$
2. $1\rightarrow (123456): 7C6.(6!/6).1!= 7.120= 840,$
3. $1\rightarrow (12) : 7C2(2!/2)= 21,$
4. $1\rightarrow(12)(34): 7C2.5C2/2= 105,$
5. $1\rightarrow (12)(34)(56): 7C2.5C2.3C2 = (21.10.3)/3!= 210/2= 105 ,$
6. $1\rightarrow(123): 7C3.2= 70,$
7. $1\rightarrow(123)(456): (7C3.4C3.2.2)/2= 35.4.2= 280,$
8. $1\rightarrow(12)(345): 7C2.5C3.2= 21.10.2= 210.2= 420, $
9. $1\rightarrow(12)(345)(67) : 
   (7C2.5C3.2)/2= 210$

$841+21+ 210+350+630= 
862+560+630=
862+1190= 2052.$

---

Taking the approach of counting (first way) would have reduced number of cases:

1.$1\rightarrow e, $
2. $1\rightarrow(123456), $
3'. $1\rightarrow(12), $
4'. $1\rightarrow(123),$

And count given for cases 3', 4' by :
$7C2.5!, 7C3.2.4!= 21.120 + 70.24
= 2520 + 1680.$
The total number of actions are:
$1+840+2520+1680= 5041.$

Extra values are: $5041 - 2052= 2989$.

The extra values are due to unwanted inequivalent actions, and double counting.
Unwanted inequivalent actions:
r. $1\rightarrow (12)(3456):
7C2.5C4.3!= 21.5.6= 630,$
s. $1\rightarrow (12)(34567): 
7C2.5C5.4!= 21.24= 504,$
t. $1\rightarrow (123)(4567): 7C3.4C4.2.3!= 35.12= 420,$

Double counting :
u. $1\rightarrow (12)(345): 7C2.5C3.2= 21.20= 420,$
v. $1\rightarrow (12)(345)(67): 7C2.5C3= 210,$
The rest values are :
 $2989-(630+504+840+210= 630+1344+210=   1974+210= 2184)= 805.$

Some must be accounted by lack of division, for cycles of the same type, as below:

w. $1\rightarrow (12)(34): 105$ extra values,
x. $1\rightarrow (12)(34)(56): 7C2.5C2.3C2 = (21.10.3).5/6= 525$ extra values,
y. $1\rightarrow (123)(456): 7C3.4C3.(3/4)= 35.3= 105$ extra values,

Still have left to account for $70=(805-(105+525+105)= 805-(210+525)= 805-(735))$ more values, and don't know which actions to seek for these.

---

But, the conclusion is clear: first way works only for complementary approach.